# C++ Guessing Game : unable to get midpoint properly

Tags: c++

I'm having a bit of trouble with a sample exercise.

The goal is to have a computer guess your number by taking the midpoint over and over until the number is reached. I have everything except that I can't seem to get "lower" working.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void playOneGame();
bool shouldPlayAgain();
int getAverage(int min, int max);
int getLow(int min, int max);
int getHigh(int min, int max);
char getResponse();

const int MAX_VALUE = 100;
const int MIN_VALUE = 0;
int AVERAGE = 50;
char choice;
int high = MAX_VALUE;
int low = MIN_VALUE;

int main()
{
    do
    {
        playOneGame();
    } while (shouldPlayAgain());

    return 0;
}

void playOneGame()
{
    cout<<"Think of a number between " << MIN_VALUE << " and " << MAX_VALUE << endl;
    getAverage(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE);
}

int getAverage(int min, int max)
{
    AVERAGE = (max - min)/2;
    getResponse();
}

int getHigh(int low, int max)
{
    low = AVERAGE;
    AVERAGE += ( high - low ) / 2;    
    getResponse();
}

int getLow(int low, int max)
{
    high = AVERAGE;
    AVERAGE -= (high - low) /2;
    getResponse();
}

char getResponse()
{
    cout << "Is it " << AVERAGE << " ?" << "  (h/l/c): " << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    if(choice == 'h' || choice == 'H') 
    {
        getHigh(low, high);
    }
    else if(choice == 'l' || choice == 'L') 
    {
        getLow(low, high);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<< "Got it!" <<endl;
    }
}

bool shouldPlayAgain()
{
    bool status;
    char choice;

    cout << "Do you want to play again? Y/N\n";
    cin >> choice;

    if(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;

    return status;
}
```

A sample output of the #15 would have it as:

```
Think of a number between 0 and 100
Is it 50 ?  (h/l/c): 
 l
Is it 25 ?  (h/l/c): 
 l
Is it 13 ?  (h/l/c): 
 h
Is it 19 ?  (h/l/c): 
 l
Is it 10 ?  (h/l/c): 
 h
Is it 14 ?  (h/l/c): 
 h
Is it 16 ?  (h/l/c): 
 l
Is it 8 ?  (h/l/c): 
 h
Is it 12 ?  (h/l/c): 
 h
Is it 14 ?  (h/l/c): 
 h
Is it 15 ?  (h/l/c): 
 c
Got it!
Do you want to play again? Y/N
```

Instead of

```
Is it 25 ?  (h/l/c): 
 l
Is it 13 ?  (h/l/c): 
 h
Is it 19 ?  (h/l/c): 
 l
Is it 10 ?  (h/l/c):
```

It should be:

```
Is it 25 ?  (h/l/c): 
 l
Is it 13 ?  (h/l/c): 
 h
Is it 19 ?  (h/l/c): 
 l
Is it 16 ?  (h/l/c):
```

Comment: It's quite hard to understand, what your exact issue is. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: A question should always consist of expected and observed output. So please add expected output.

Comment: It runs exactly as stated in the example given. https://repl.it/LOBF/0

Comment: Ah, sorry. This is my first time with formatting so I apologize for that. I'll try to fix t hat.

The problem is that instead of taking using the average as the new "lower", it'll keep using zero effectively just dividing it in two.

It works fine for "higher" as shown by

25 - > 13

And I prompt for "higher"

It'll take the midpoint and bring back 19. 

When I prompt for "lower" it should be the midpoint between 13 and 19, but instead it takes the midpoint of 0 and 19.

Comment: Your way of calculating the average is wrong, the average of two numbers isn't `(max - min) / 2`, but it is `(max + min) / 2`. And when re-calculating the average, you should again use the same formula to calculate the average (`(high + low) / 2`) instead of subtracting or adding something to the current average.

Comment: You should avoid using global variables.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky Yeah, I read that global variables should be avoided (unless it's a const value). I played around with it a bit but couldn't get it working. After I have this code working properly, I want to try rewriting it without the use of the many globals I have in place right now.

Comment: You could replace all the (misnamed) `get...` functions with `void guess(int low, int high) { int mid = (low + high) / 2; /*prompt*/ if (isHigh) { guess(mid, high); } else if (isLow) { guess(low, mid); } else { /*won*/ } }`

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your variable scoping.

variable "low" here has a local scope. it use the value passed into the function

```
int getHigh(int low, int max)
{
    low = AVERAGE;
```

assigning to low means assigning to the local variable, not the global variable

variable "high" here has a global scope. It uses the value assigned anywhere on this page

```
int getLow(int low, int max)
{
    high = AVERAGE;
    AVERAGE -= (high - low) /2;
```

also, try to  use the return value from the function.

Comment: Ah! That's where I got it wrong. I used the wrong variable. Switching it to "min" rather than "low" makes it work just fine.

Now it's time for some editing to remove my many global variables.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Average should be calculate as (min+max)/2.

```
int getAverage(int min, int max)

{

    AVERAGE = (max + min)/2;// Changed average calculation

    getResponse();

}

int getHigh()

{
    low = AVERAGE;//Change the lower limit to new Average

        getAverage(low,high);//Again an Average value is alone needed which can be done with the function existing already

}

int getLow()

{
    high = AVERAGE;//Change the higher limit to new Average

        getAverage(low,high);
}

char getResponse()

{
    cout << "Is it " << AVERAGE << " ?" << "  (h/l/c): " << endl;

    cin >> choice;

    if(choice == 'h' || choice == 'H') 

    {

    getHigh();//Just the max value for Average changes. So no need to pass the values. Also low and high are kept global already

  }

  else if(choice == 'l' || choice == 'L') 
  {

    getLow();// Same as getHigh();

/*
getHigh() and getLow() can be removed and the parameters can be sent directly to getAverage() directly from here to simplify the code further.

*/

  }

  else 

  {

    cout<< "Got it!" <<endl;

  }

}
```

Output with sample #15

```
Think of a number between 0 and 100
Is it 50 ?  (h/l/c): 
l
Is it 25 ?  (h/l/c): 
l
Is it 12 ?  (h/l/c): 
h
Is it 18 ?  (h/l/c): 
l
Is it 15 ?  (h/l/c): 
c
Got it!
Do you want to play again? Y/N
n
```

This reduces the number of attempts in calculating

Answer (score 0):

You had overritter your static variables `low` and `high`. Some more comments:

Please consider using some exsisting library for your [bisection](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/roots/roots_noderiv/bisect.html).

Please use proper formater (e.g. clang-format).
Please do use `using namespace std;` Use string instead of char.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void playOneGame();
bool shouldPlayAgain();
int getAverage(int min, int max);
int getLow();
int getHigh();
std::string getResponse();

const int MAX_VALUE = 100;
const int MIN_VALUE = 0;
int AVERAGE = (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE) / 2;
int high = MAX_VALUE;
int low = MIN_VALUE;

int main() {
    do
        playOneGame();
    while (shouldPlayAgain());

    return 0;
}

void playOneGame() {
    cout << "Think of a number between " << MIN_VALUE << " and " << MAX_VALUE
         << endl;
    getAverage(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE);
}

int getAverage(int min, int max) {
    AVERAGE = (max - min) / 2;
    getResponse();
}

int getHigh() {
    low = AVERAGE;
    AVERAGE += (high - low) / 2;
    getResponse();
}

int getLow() {
    high = AVERAGE;
    AVERAGE -= (high - low) / 2;
    getResponse();
}

std::string getResponse() {
    std::string choice;
    std::cout << "Is it " << AVERAGE << " ?"
              << "  (h/l/c): " << std::endl;

    std::cin >> choice;

    if (choice == "h" || choice == "H")
        getHigh();
    else if (choice == "l" || choice == "L")
        getLow();
    else
        cout << "Got it!" << endl;
}

bool shouldPlayAgain() {
    bool status;

    std::string choice;

    cout << "Do you want to play again? Y/N\n";

    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == "y" || choice == "Y")
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;

    return status;
}
```